# Windows Phone 7.1 - Isolated storage settings using ToggleSwitch to turn sound on and off

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to create and isolated storage setting where the user can turn sound or vibrate alerts (or both together) on or off depending on the state of the toggle switch in the user settings page. I'm using an mvvm framework and need to reference the Setting class within the MainViewModel class. I realise that I need to insert an if statement as part of the process but are running into difficulty.

Settings.xaml

```
<!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <toolbox:ToggleSwitch Name="MobileSound" Header="Sound"></toolbox:ToggleSwitch>
        <toolbox:ToggleSwitch Name="MobileVibrate" Header="Vibrate" Margin="6,119,6,371"></toolbox:ToggleSwitch>

        <Slider Height="84" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,310,0,0" Name="slider1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="418" Value="1" Minimum="1" />
        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,274,0,0" Name="Difficulty" Text="Refresh Timer" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135" />
    </Grid>
```

Settings.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Windows.Navigation;

namespace MobileApplicationSample
{
/// <summary>
/// Description for Setting.
/// </summary>
public partial class Setting : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public Setting()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("into the app");
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Retrieving values");
            MobileSound.IsChecked = (bool)settings["sound"];
            MobileVibrate.IsChecked = (bool)settings["vibrate"];
            slider1.Value = (Int16)settings["diff"];

        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("First Time using the app");             
            settings.Add("sound", false);
            settings.Add("vibrate", false);
            settings.Add("diff", 1);
            settings.Save();
        }

    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exiting, so save now");
        settings["vibrate"] = MobileVibrate.IsChecked;
        settings["sound"] = MobileSound.IsChecked;
        settings["diff"] = (Int16)slider1.Value;
        settings.Save();
    }

    public IsolatedStorageSettings settings { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

first define a toggle switch ...
i am using one toggle switch you can make changes according for 2.

```
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch  Foreground="Black" Background="Black" FontWeight="Medium" IsChecked="{Binding LocationSetting, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource appSettings}}" Margin="0,15,0,0" />
```

then in your settings class .

```
  public class AppSettings : ViewModelBase
  {
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings;

    const string LocationSettingName = "sound";
    const bool LocationSettingDefault = false;

    public AppSettings()
            {
                // Get the settings for this application.
                settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
            }

            public bool AddOrUpdateValue(string Key, Object value)
            {
                bool valueChanged = false;

                // If the key exists
                if (settings.Contains(Key))
                {
                    // If the value has changed
                    if (settings[Key] != value)
                    {
                        // Store the new value
                        settings[Key] = value;
                        valueChanged = true;
                    }
                }
                // Otherwise create the key.
                else
                {
                    settings.Add(Key, value);
                    valueChanged = true;
                }
                return valueChanged;
            }

            public T GetValueOrDefault<T>(string Key, T defaultValue)
            {
                T value;

                // If the key exists, retrieve the value.
                if (settings.Contains(Key))
                {
                    value = (T)settings[Key];
                }
                // Otherwise, use the default value.
                else
                {
                    value = defaultValue;
                }
                return value;
            }

            public void Save()
            {
                settings.Save();
            }

            public bool LocationSetting
            {
                get
                {
                    return GetValueOrDefault<bool>(LocationSettingName, LocationSettingDefault);
                }
                set
                {
                    if (AddOrUpdateValue(LocationSettingName, value))
                    {
                        Save();
                    }
                }
            }
      }
```